# How to achieve distributed transactions in of Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

One of my controller action is like

```
def create
 App.transaction do
  app = App.create_new_app(params["app_alias"])
  campaign = Campaign.create_new_campaign(params)
  user = User.create_new_user(params)
 end
end
```

[This documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) says that "a transaction acts on a single database connection"" and "fully distributed transactions are beyond the scope of Active Record." How can I create something like if there is some exception in creating user or campaign then app is also rollback and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the same documentation you link to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), you can create the effect of a distributed transaction by nesting transactions for the different classes:

```
Student.transaction do
  Course.transaction do
    course.enroll(student)
    student.units += course.units
  end
end
```

This is described as an inelegant workaround, but it's likely that anything else suggested here would be as well.

Of course, you only need to do this if each of your classes is stored to a different database - if all your models are in the same database, a single `.transaction` block will have the desired effect - any failure during any part will rollback all the changes.

Comment: I admit I haven't tried it, but it certainly looks like it ought to work. Perhaps you could add to your question the code you've tried using, the results you get, and what you want/expect it to do?

Comment: i have written the same code i am using. every model method is calling some method to the respective method which will do some db operation.

Comment: I don't know what 'the same code i am using' means, but nested transactions are the suggested solution to this problem. Unless you can show that they don't work and how, I fail to see what you plan to accomplish here. Best of luck, regardless.

Comment: thanks man for your help .. its working now. the only thing i missed here was proper nesting the db action which you want to perform last should be on First in the Transaction and so on.. :)